# How do you add a boolean attribute in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I'm trying to output the following html using an html helper in asp.net mvc 2:

```
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="" autofocus />
```

I'm using this code now:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
```

and I've tried

```
// results in <input ... autofocus="" />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { autofocus="" }) %>

// does not compile
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { autofocus=null }) %>
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm looking for using an html helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to write your own helper for this.  The default helpers output key/value pairs.  Under the hood it uses a TagBuilder to construct the tag.  For tag attributes it uses the format `{0}="{1}"` to format the key/value pairs for the attributes and their values.

Comment: I gave it some time, it appears you're right and you were first, so I'll accept. I'm still sad tho. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Html helpers generate XHTML. What you are trying to achieve is:

1. Not XHTML (attributes need to have values, even empty)
2. Not W3C standard (no `autofocus` attribute for the input tag)

If you want to generate such markup you will need to do it manually or write your own helper.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long ago and far away, but wasn't there an old rule that you could enter such attributes as

> required="required"

This appears to work in FireFox, Chrome and Opera, but not Safari, nor of course IE8, which is my companies standard, (queue trombone...Waa, waa, waa. ;)